# How to get papyrus houseplant to grow more fully?

Tags: plant-care

Inherited this when it was full and thick but dried and browned stalks. Hadn’t been watered in weeks.  Cut all back, repotted as it was root bound, and surprised it started growing again. But it’s very thin. I had cut off tops of a few viable stems and propagated. The pic shows two tallest stems and there are several shorter stems opened or close to opening up. How do I get it to be more bushy? I cut one to propagate but there are so few that I don’t want to cut more. Do I just wait and hope more pop up?

[image: papirus grown tall]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there’s not enough light now. Check that it is near the window.
Also, the plant has been under stress before, so add some fertilizers for leafy plants and it will start to recover. Normally, papyrus should be bushy, as you correctly mentioned :)